# How to store "macros" in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apartment-gem

I have a multi-tenant rails app that uses the apartment gem. When I use rails console, I am constantly calling Apartment::Tenant.switch to navigate between apartments. I would like to create a config file somewhere that where I can abreviate this call to something shorter to type. How would I go about doing this so that when I start up the console with `rails console` this shorter call is available? I was imagining something like

```
swtich = Apartment::Tenant.switch
```

And then whenever I call switch then it calls the original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. not actually macros but we have dynamic_method define right.

so u can do this in your rails console:

```
define_method :bar do
  Apartment::Tenant.switch
end
```

and then you can call `bar` method as short for your method.

To add it in `initializers` i have created one file say `bar.rb` in initializers folder.

then I have done it , I don't if its ideal:

```
class Object
    def bar
        Apartment::Tenant.switch
    end
end
```

restart you console and call bar

Comment: can I put this in an initializers file?

Comment: yes you can , but i don't know if its right to open object class and methods into it. let me update the answer

Comment: I just added define_method to .~/.irbrc . It works great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like global variables, but you can place this in an `initalizers` file:

```
$switch = (Class.new do
  def [](tenant, &block)
    Apartment::Tenant.switch(tenant, &block)
  end
end).new
```

and then use it like this:

```
$switch['tenant_name'] do
  ....
end
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

There *has* to be a better way of doing this and I don't recommend this whatsoever. Drop this into an initializer or `application.rb` or similar.

```
module Kernel
  def switch
    Apartment::Tenant.switch
  end
end
```

will allow you to simply call `switch` in your console. You'll probably break some other stuff though, and you should take steps to ensure that this is only accessible via the console.